# mvc 5 SendEmailAsync with image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to send a confirm email when a user registers on my website.

The C# is -

```
string baseDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

string confirmRegistrationEmail = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(baseDirectory + "Content\\ConfirmRegistration.html").Replace("#logo", baseDirectory + "Content\\Images\\logo.png");

await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(_user.Id, "Confirm your account", confirmRegistrationEmail);
```

which loads my ConfirmRegistration.html file from the file system. That file is -

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="#logo" alt="Logo" align="middle">
    <br>
    <b>Thank you for registering with Example Website.</b> Your account has been created.<br>
    <p align ="justify">  <a href="#callbackURL">Click here to confirm and complete the registration process.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I can't get the logo to appear.

IS there something special I need to do to get that image to appear?

Also, I need to continue to use `SendEmailAsync`

Comment: you have to include it in an absolute url.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include it in an absolute url.